# manipulating jquery options on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use a jquery plugin and want the user to be able to manipulate an option (LENGTH parameter) him/her-self.

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
    $('#green').smartpaginator({
        totalrecords: <? echo $count;?>,
        length: 3,
        recordsperpage: 3,
        datacontainer: 'theTable',
        dataelement: 'tr',
        initval: 0,
        next: 'Next',
        prev: 'Prev',
        first: 'First',
        last: 'Last',
        theme: 'green'
    });
});
```

i want the LENGTH parameter to be changed. The code for the select box with onchange event is not the matter of interest. the question is how to make the change, also dom-wise, at the jquery options.

Since i've never manipulated javascript code i have no idea how to select the options with dom or most efficiently.

Comment: What value to you want to change `length` to? Where does that value come from? Does smartpaginator allow you to change options after initialization?

Comment: 1+2 to another number the user inputs in a inputbox with an onchange-element. 3 i don't know but if i change the value with firebug the change reflects on the page immediately, so i guess Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no `setLength()`function available for the paginator? I would probably create a function like that for the paginator plugin and pass the length to that. Then attach en event handler that would call that function when the user changes the length.